# Powershell logging from invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have a script that includes a function for logging.
The function writes log to $msg variable then writes the message to the screen.
i can redirect this output to a .txt file for logging.

I need to run the script to multiple servers using invoke-command 
and write the log output to a txt file on the computer running the script.

I am trying to figure out how to output $msg in the write-log function from the PSSession and return it so I can create a master log file for all the servers.  Should I create and populate a custom object?  Not sure how to do that and get the results back from the remote session.

Can this even be done?

Here is an example of the code I am using and what the log file output should look like:

```
$servers = 'Server1','Server2'
$logfile = 'c:\scripts\logs\Reg-DLL-log.txt'

foreach($server in $servers){
    invoke-command -cn $server -sb{
        Param($server)

        Function write-log{
            [cmdletbinding()]
            Param(
                [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
                [string] $Message,
                [Parameter()] [ValidateSet(“Error”, “Warn”, “Info”)]
                [string] $Level = “Info”,
                [Parameter()] [ValidateRange(1,30)]
                [Int16] $Indent = 0
            )
            $msg = "{0} {1}{2}:{3}" -f (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), $Level.ToUpper(), (" " * $Indent), $Message
                #This is output to screen
                switch ($Level) {
                    'Error' { Write-Host ('{0}{1}' -f (" " * $Indent), $Message) -ForegroundColor 'Red'}
                    'Warn' { Write-Host ('{0}{1}' -f (" " * $Indent), $Message) -ForegroundColor 'Yellow'}
                    'Info' { Write-Host ('{0}{1}' -f (" " * $Indent), $Message) -ForegroundColor 'white'}
        }}

        write-log -message 'Begin DLL registration for $server' -level Info
        $RegFile = "cimwin32.dll"
        regsvr32 $RegFile /s
        write-log -message 'registered $RegFile' -level Info
        write-log -message 'End DLL registration for $server' -level Info

    } -ArgumentList $server
}
```

Log output to Reg-DLL-log.txt should look like this:

```
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:Begin DLL registration for Server1
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:registered cimwin32.dll
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:End DLL registration for Server1
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:Begin DLL registration for Server2
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:registered cimwin32.dll
2013-06-19 11:25:12 INFO:End DLL registration for Server2
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I ended up making the entire foreach a variable by begining the script with: 
$out = Foreach{.......}. 
I then piped the variable at the end

$out | Out-File $logfile

Here is a sample:

```
$out = foreach($server in $servers){
    invoke-command -cn $server -scriptblock {
        Param($server)
        "{0} :Begin DLL registration for {1}" -f (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),$server
    } -ArgumentList $server
}

$out | Out-File $logfile
```

Comment: Your answer is conceptually identical to Ansgar so why add it and accept your own answer as the solution? I.m.o. this denies Ansgar's answer the credit it deserves...

Answer (score 31):

As [documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx), `Invoke-Command` returns all command output, so you could use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host` and pipe the returned output into a file. There's no fancy coloring with `Write-Output`, though. You could, however, write 'Info', 'Warn' and 'Error' level messages to the correct streams using `Write-Output`, `Write-Warning` and `Write-Error`. Also, you may want to suppress output from `regsvr32`.

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScriptBlock {
    Param($server)

    Function write-log {
      ...
      switch ($Level) {
        'Error' { Write-Error $msg }
        'Warn'  { Write-Warning $msg }
        'Info'  { Write-Output $msg }
      }
    }

    write-log -message 'Begin DLL registration for $server' -level Info
    $RegFile = "cimwin32.dll"
    regsvr32 $RegFile /s | Out-Null
    write-log -message 'registered $RegFile' -level Info
    write-log -message 'End DLL registration for $server' -level Info
  } -ArgumentList $server | Out-File -Append $masterLog
}
```