# I can't seem to capture warning output from a remote Invoke-command call

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

The following SO question seems to think it's possible:  [Powershell logging from invoke-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198130/powershell-logging-from-invoke-command)

The top answer (not the accepted answer), mentions the documentation states that Inovke-Command returns everything, which indeed it does say that, emphasis mine.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

> The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer
>   and **returns all output from the commands, including errors**.

Note that $PSVersionTable.PSVersion outputs 4.0 (Powershell ISE).

Here is the code in question

```
$out = Invoke-Command -Session $sess {
  Write-Warning 'w1'
}


'--'
$out
'--'
```

And the output

```
WARNING: w1
--
--
```

What I was hoping for was:

```
--
w1
--
```

Meaning, I want to be able to capture the output from the warning stream.

Any explanations?  How do I do this?

Comment: If you want to redirect warning stream to output, then use `3>&1`.

Comment: @user4003407 that does not work.

Comment: I just ran into this bug too.  Tried every permutation.  Can't figure out how to incercept the warnings from a remoting session.  I can passthrough the WarningPreference at best.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WarningAction and WarningVariable parameters of Invoke-Command.

Comment: That does not work.